# Vuetify: v-autocomplete doesn't highlight text when using the item and selection slots

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm losing the text highlighting when using the slots

https://codepen.io/dhika345/pen/vYZEXNo

I've used `parent.genFilteredText(item.title)` but doesn't solve it. I don't know what it is actually

You can comment the `item` and `selection` slots and click the `v-autocomplete` box to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

you have to omitted `hide-selected` in `v-autocomplete` tag and after that, you need to use the below code inside `v-autocomplete` tag.

code:

```
     <template
        slot="item"
        slot-scope="{ parent, item, tile }"
      >
           <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title
                v-html="parent.genFilteredText(item.title)"
            > 
            </v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </template>
```

Comment: Would you explain why we need the `v-list` and remove `hide-selected` ? anyway, you can fork the codepen, fix it, and share it right away

Comment: yes sure.
1) when you'd like to create a custom part to v-autocomplete, you need to create a template inside v-autocomplete. if you want to show a list of items then you use 'v-list' inside the template.
2) hide-selected means: Do not display in the select menu items that are already selected, So to display the selected items, we need to delete the `hide-selected`
3) https://codepen.io/zahraKaramii/pen/ZEyYMQX